# Skype Desktop API Messaging

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am using the desktop api to buid a group chat window in my application. If I use skype on a mobile device can I  join the same chat group?

For anyone who stumbles on this. I've found that the Persistent Chat SDK should provide me with the functionality needed to achieve this. I'm still playing around with the code so will come back with a definitive answer.

Comment: Please keep noted that Skype for Business (SfB) isn´t the same as Skype for consumer (SfC). So which version you are refering to? Is that the cost free skype version (then it is SfC) or did you use something which you have installed, then its SfB.

Comment: @BastianW I was referring to the SfC version however if such functionality is only available on the SfB version then I'll go down that road.